# Esp8266 Сессии Авторизация

Tags: сессия, wifi, микроконтроллеры, esp8266

**Суть Вопроса**

Как в esp8266 использовать сессию. Хотя бы как передать индикатор в ответ браузеру чтобы он ее запомнил. и как потом из запроса от браузера получить ключ сессии. Хранение сессии организую сам.

---

**Пред История**

С помощью ESP8266 Можно создавать разные устройства, и не напрягаться по поводу защиты. Так как для управления нужно знать пароль к вай фай сети, но проблема возникает тогда когда для удаленного контроля нужно открыть мост в Интернет, И теперь человеку из Интернета уже не нужно знать пароль от вай фай. Все ворота открыты. И тут нужно сделать авторизацию, но как без сессий? Ну иле их подобия самодельного.
Мне не нужен громоздкий код. Мне нужно понимание как это сделать. То есть как отправить ключ сессии чтобы браузер запомнил его, и как его добывать с каждого запроса. *Не хотел бы все делать через js который смог бы добивать индикатор в начале сохранять в кеше, и потом при каждом запросе слать его как один из аргументов, вариант но не очень.*

---

У меня в арсенале Esp8266 01, Esp8266 07, Esp8266 12. Esp8266 01 глючные какие то по этому в серьёзе их не использую.

---

**Ответ:** рабочий код

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>


String ssid = "botemm_LAN";
String password = "passwor1";
int ConnectNum = 20;
int Mode = 0; 

ESP8266WebServer server(80); //Server on port 80


//Режим клиента
bool WiFiStartClient(String Ssid, String Pas)
{
   // WiFi.softAPdisconnect();
   // WiFi.disconnect();

    int i = 0;
    //Client
    {  
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP); //WIFI_STA
      Mode = WIFI_AP;
      WiFi.begin(Ssid, Pas);
    
      // Wait for connection
      while (1) {
        
        if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) //Если подключились 1
        {
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.print("Connected to ");
        Serial.println(Ssid);
        Serial.print("IP address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        return true;
        }

      if(i>=ConnectNum) //времмя подключения прошло 0
      {
        return false;
      }
        
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
        i++;
      }
    }
      return false;
}

IPAddress myIP;
//Старт как точка доступа
bool WiFiStartPoint(String Ssid, String Pas)
{
   //WiFi.softAPdisconnect();
   // WiFi.disconnect();
  //Server Point
  {
    IPAddress myIP;
    myIP = WiFi.softAPIP(); //Get IP address
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);           //Only Access point
    Mode = WIFI_STA;
    WiFi.softAP(Ssid, Pas);  //Start HOTspot removing password will disable security   


        Serial.println("");
        Serial.print("Create to ");
        Serial.println(Ssid);
        Serial.print("IP address: ");
        Serial.println("192.168.4.1");
  }  
  return true;
}


//Активировать сесии. они не будут работать без этого бреда сохранять да получаь нет
void InitCookie()
{
    const char * headerkeys[] = {"User-Agent", "Cookie"} ;
  size_t headerkeyssize = sizeof(headerkeys) / sizeof(char*);
  //ask server to track these headers
  server.collectHeaders(headerkeys, headerkeyssize);
}




int c = 0;
void handleRoot() {

    String arg1 = server.arg("cmd");
    if(arg1 == "login")
    {
      String S = "User=";
      S+=c;
      server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
      server.sendHeader("Set-Cookie", S);
      server.sendHeader("Set-Cookie", "ESPSESSIONID=1");
      Serial.println("CookieSet: "); Serial.println(c);
      c++;
    }

String STR = "";

  if (server.hasHeader("Cookie")) 
  {
    String coo = server.header("Cookie");
    STR += coo;
    Serial.println("Cookie: "); Serial.println(coo);
  }



    
    server.send(200, "text/html" ,STR);
     return;
  
}






void setup(void) {




  Serial.begin(74880);
  //Подключиться к точке доступа, если нет создать свою
  if(!WiFiStartClient( ssid, password))
    {
      Serial.println("");  Serial.println("error not conected");
       if(!WiFiStartPoint("EspServerLib","12345678"))
       Serial.println("error not started");

    }





  server.on("/", handleRoot);      //Which routine to handle at root location 
 // server.onNotFound(handleNotFound); //Не существующая страница


 InitCookie();
  
  server.begin();    
}


void loop(void) {

 
//if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { //Check WiFi connection status
 
  
server.handleClient();
 // MDNS.update();
}
```

Получить строку сессий
String coo = server.header("Cookie");
Отправить куки в браузер
server.sendHeader("Set-Cookie", "user=botemm");

Надеюсь кому то поможет

Comment: Не уверен, что вам это поможет. Вы пробовали авторизацию по клиентским X509 -сертификатам? как здесь https://medium.com/@sevcsik/authentication-using-https-client-certificates-3c9d270e8326

Comment: Для [HTTP-печенек](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Куки) js не нужен. Достаточно серверу принять логин/пароль в POST запросе от обычной формы и прислать ответ с заголовком SetCookie. Инфраструктура браузера будет делать все уже без вашего участия. Это то, что нужно? Мне кажется, что да.

Comment: Великого смысла эта затея не имеет. хотя через куки работает. даже сам делал. только вот 2-3 запроса в браузере одновременно и эта чудожелезка китайской промышленности просто уходит в ребут из-за нехватки ресурсов. лучше используйте более легковесные протоколы, нежели хттп.

Comment: mrEvgenX, Думаю да, вопрос был как это сделать на ESP но ваш комментарий натолкнул меня на мысль что http заголовок это обычный текст который ESP формирует автоматически вместе с телом. Мне просто нужно сформировать все вручную. Насколько понял в заголовок просто нужно вставить Set-Cookie: UsID=МойКлюч. И браузер сам ид запомнит и будет присылать с каждым запросом. Пасиб буду пробовать.  Yakov У меня веб интерфейс, других протоколов не знаю.

Comment: Ответ нужно писать не в текст вопроса. А в поле ниже "Ваш ответ".

Comment: И пометить его как верный, тоже не помешает!